# Google App Engine w/ Django wont render 960GS

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, 960.gs

I'm trying to create a website using `GAE(Google App Engine)` as the server and Having pages rendered using the `GAE Django API`. The `CSS` style I'd like to use is the `960 Grid System`, specifically the adaptive version found [here](http://adapt.960.gs/).

My page is being rendered with Django in GAE as usual:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler): 

    def get(self):
        featuredPic = "img/featuredPic.jpg"

        values = {
                  'featuredPic' : featuredPic,
                  }

        self.response.out.write(template.render('index.html', values))


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

And my `index.html` file also includes the code neccassarry for an adaptive grid system:

```
<script src="/js/adapt.js"></script>
<script>
    // Edit to suit your needs.
    var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
        // Where is your CSS?
        path : '/css/',

        // false = Only run once, when page first loads.
        // true = Change on window resize and page tilt.
        dynamic : true,

        // First range entry is the minimum.
        // Last range entry is the maximum.
        // Separate ranges by "to" keyword.
        range : [ '0px    to 760px  = mobile.min.css',
                '760px  to 980px  = 720.min.css',
                '980px  to 1280px = 960.min.css',
                '1280px to 1600px = 1200.min.css',
                '1600px to 1940px = 1560.min.css',
                '1940px to 2540px = 1920.min.css',

                '2540px           = 2520.min.css' ]
    };
</script>
```

Also I am including the css,js,img, and other folders in the `app.yaml`, yet despite all this the resulting HTML does not follow the 960 Grid System classes I have set to the divs. Does GAE disable JS or am I making some other mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer my question but I instead switched to the successor of 960.gs, Unsemantic, available here. It works really well with my project, as it was pretty much what I was looking for in the adaptive version of 960.gs. Also I had no issues setting it up.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I am not that good at GAE, but I can help you, i guess.

I've also made a page on GAE and that has also template html file which uses the .js and .css files

At the template html file, I've written the script tag like the below.

`<script type="application/x-javascript" src="iui/iui.js"></script>`

and i put the .js file at the below path.

`<app_name>\iui\iui.js`

`<app_name>` has the models.py, urls.py, views.py, etc.

In addition, I've added the following statements on my app.yaml, "muchart" is `<app_name>`

```
app.yaml
...
handlers:
- url: /muchart/js
  static_dir: muchart/js

- url: /muchart/iui
  static_dir: muchart/iui
```